# Java 8 stream map to new Objects

Tags: java, map, java-8, java-stream

Как можно замапить стрим в новые объекты? Или, эти примеры что не равнозначны?

```
list.stream().map(new SomeObject()::convertToSomeObject)

list.stream().map(item -> new SomeObject().convertToSomeObject(item))

public SomeObject convertToSomeObject(Item item) {
    this.name = item.getName;
    this.value = item.getValue;
    return this;
}
```

в первом случае у меня все замапилось одним объектом

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Почему не работает первый вариант

При выполнении строчки

```
list.stream().map(new SomeObject()::convertToSomeObject)
```

происходит следующее:

- **до вызова метода `map`** создаётся новый объект `SomeObject`
- ссылка на метод этого объекта передаётся в качестве параметра-лямбды в метод `map`
- берутся по очереди все элементы старого потока, к ним применяется переданный метод
- из полученных в результате применения метода новых объектов создаётся новый поток

Здесь объект `SomeObject` создаётся ровно один раз, и так как его метод `convertToSomeObject` всегда возвращает единственный созданный экземпляр, то и получается, что новый поток состоит из ссылок на один и тот же объект. При этом метод `convertToSomeObject` вызывался для каждого элемента потока и каждый раз значения полей объекта перезаписывались

### Почему работает второй варинат

При выполнении строчки

```
list.stream().map(item -> new SomeObject().convertToSomeObject(item))
```

происходит следующее:

- **никаких объектов `SomeObject` до вызова `map` не создаётся**
- в метод `map` передаётся лямбда-функция, которая работает как обычная функция:

  - принимает объект `item`
  - создаёт новый экземпляр класса `SomeObject`
  - вызывает метод `convertToSomeObject` у созданного экземпляра
  - возвращает результат вызова метода `convertToSomeObject`, то есть только что созданный экземпляр класса `SomeObject`
- заметим, что **лямбда-функция создаёт новый объект при каждом вызове**

### Как исправить первый вариант

- написать конструктор `SomeObject`, принимающий `Item` в качестве параметра:

  ```
  public SomeObject(Item item) {
      this.name = item.getName();
  }

  list.stream().map(SomeObject::new)
  ```
- добавить в класс `SomeObject` статический метод, принимающий `Item` и возвращающий `SomeObject`:

  ```
  public static SomeObject convertToSomeObject(Item item) {
      SomeObject object = new SomeObject();
      object.name = item.getName();
      return object;
  }

  list.stream().map(SomeObject::convertToSomeObject)
  ```
- Перенести метод `convertToSomeObject` в класс `Item`:

  ```
  public SomeObject convertToSomeObject() {
      SomeObject object = new SomeObject();
      object.name = this.getName();
      return object;
  }

  list.stream().map(Item::convertToSomeObject)
  ```